# ¿Cómo se pueden cerrar todas las aplicaciones que hay abiertas desde consola de windows?

Tags: windows, cmd, batch, consola

¿Hay alguna forma de cerrar todas las aplicaciones que tiene el equipo abiertas desde la consola de windwos (cmd)? Por ejemplo, tiene abierto el Google Chrome, el Word y la calculadora, y al ejecutar el/los comandos (desde consola o desde un archivo .bat) que se cierren estas aplicaciones.

He estado probando el comnaod `taskkill` pero a esta comnado le tienes que indicar o el nombre del proceso o el PID. Yo busco algo para cerrar todas las aplicaciones.

He estado buscando por internet pero no he encontrado ninguno que pueda hacer algo de esto.

Saludos.

Comment: Es probable que antes tengas que recopilar los PID e irlas cerrando con un bucle.

Comment: Perfecto. Es lo que había pensado después de formular la pregunta. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mira con el comando taskkill podes matar varias a la vez.

Con esta linea podes matar todos los procesos del usuario pepito

> taskkill /FI "USERNAME eq pepito" /F

o por ejemplo matar todos los que tengan iexplorer de nombre

> taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe

Mirando el tema del filtro lo podes manejar bastante.
Un saludo y espero que sirva